# pagination with stacked z-index images

Tags: html, css, pagination

I'm trying to create a pagination that looks like it's being held by a monster. [You can see it at the bottom of this page](http://www.customkidart.com/gallery.html)

What I've done is create two images. One of the full image of the monster with a z-index of -10. And a second image of JUST the claws over the pagination with a z-index of 10.

The problem is, since the claws images sits on top of the pagination code, it's blocking it from being used (since it's basically in the way).

I don't even know if what I'm attempting is even possible. I basically just want a pagination that looks like a monster is holding it up.

Here is my code:

```css
.pagination_monster {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 138px;
  background-image: url(../images/pagination_monster.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 141px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: -10;
}
.pagination_monster_claws {
  position: relative;
  top: 55px;
  background-image: url(../images/pagination_monster_claws.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 10 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row text-center ">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="pagination_monster_claws"></div>
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li>
        <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">4</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">5</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="pagination_monster"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Again, I'm not sure if this is even doable. Any insight that can point me the right direction would be extremely helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- First, i love your idea, so cool.
- Second, to your question, i think you should add `pointer-events: none;` to your div with class `pagination_monster_claws`. The attribute allow you click through the image like it not there

Comment: You're my hero! Thank you!! :)

Comment: Glad i could help!